# Hyper-V Feature Greyed Out in Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

I am trying to setup a lab on my personal machine. I currently run Win 8.1 Pro. I have gone into Programs & Features to turn on this feature. When I expand the Hyper-V selection. The Hyper-V option is greyed out. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Requirements

> Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System
>
> 64 bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
>
> 4GB system RAM at minimum
>
> BIOS-level Hardware Virtualization support

**Step 1**: Enable hardware virtualization support in BIOS

**BIOS** -> **Security** -> **Virtualization Technology** -> **Enabled**

Save and reboot your system.

**Step 2**: Enable HyperV in Windows Features

[image: Windows Features HyperV]

After installing feature, reboot system. After this you should be able to create VMs trough your HyperV.

[Step-by-step guide for enabling HyperV in Windows 8.1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/03/11/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx)